# ORA-00906: "missing left parenthesis"

Tags: sql, oracle

I try to add some constraints but no matter what I do, I get this message, that I m missing left parenthesis..

1.

```
alter table CUSTOMER
add unique customer.username (username);
```

2.

```
ALTER TABLE CUSTOMER 
ADD CONSTRAINT CHECK customer.credit_type (credit_type,'high','average','low');
```

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

It seems like you're looking for this syntax:

```
ALTER TABLE customer
ADD CONSTRAINT username_unique UNIQUE (username);

ALTER TABLE customer
ADD CONSTRAINT check_credit_type CHECK (credit_type IN ('high','average','low'));
```